# Aptana studio Web browser executable does not exist at location error

Tags: aptana

I installed Aptana studio 3. Then i create simple html page. Then i click run and get error:

```
Web browser executable does not exist at location error
```

In menu -> window -> preferences -> Web browser i have firefox field with /usr/bin/firefox path.

How can i fix it?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure web browser at menu Run/Run Configurations.../Web Browser. Then select one of configurations and fill its "Browser executable" field.

Cheers,
Max